# Can I get rid of Xcode's CGContextErase warning?

Tags: xcode

I think I must have something wrong with my copy of Xcode.

I get an error logged to the console every time I build and run any target.

```
 May  3 12:05:19 MBP-Retina.local testProject[2768] <Error>: The function `CGContextErase' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
```

I am not calling CGContextErase.  If I add a symbolic breakpoint that breaks when CGContextErase is called it appears to be called by NSApplicationMain.

I can't believe that everyone gets this.
What's wrong with my copy of Xcode, and how can I fix it?
Any ideas?  Thanks.